# Read BitmapImage from Zip archive

Tags: c#, wpf, zip, bitmapimage

For a WPF project I need to read a BitmapImage from a Zip file. The original fileformat is .png I know how to do this directly from a file system and that is working fine. From a Zip file, unfortunately the image is not shown, though an image seems to be read.

I created a simple test project:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

    public BitmapImage RouteImage { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadBitmap();
        DataContext = RouteImage;
        }

    public void LoadBitmap()
        {
        RouteImage = new BitmapImage();
        var PackedFile = @"D:\Temp\MainContent.ap";
        try
            {
                {
                using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(PackedFile))
                    {
                    var file = archive.GetEntry("RouteInformation/image.png");
                    if (file != null)
                        {
                        using (var zipEntryStream = file.Open())
                            {
                            RouteImage.BeginInit();
                            RouteImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                            RouteImage.StreamSource = zipEntryStream;
                            RouteImage.EndInit();
                            return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        catch (Exception e)
            {
            var s = "Exception: " + e.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML code looks like this:

```
<Image Height="128" Width="256"  Source="{Binding BitmapImage}"/>
```

In the debugger it looks like the stream is created and bound to the BitmapImage, but the width and height are set to  1. so I think something is wrong withe the reading of the data in the zip file.

Comment: Shouldn't be the Source="{Binding}" since the DataContext is the BitmapImage?

Comment: First of all. Your Window DataContext is not your BitmapImage. Create a new class as your window DataContext=new yourclass for example, (ViewModel that have to implement inotifypropertychanged interface) and make a property. (This property name should be the same as Binding source name in the xaml part.) After you set your BitmapImage invoke your OnPropertyChanged.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, S.Toniolo I tested, but it does not make any difference. Yes, you can leave out the binding object if it is unambiguous, but seems not to harm using it explicitly. I posted testing code, in real world the class I want to expose has a lot more data to bind. Youstill may be right, I am still quite confused about WPF struggling to learn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the exact reason, but it seems necessary to copy the zip stream to an intermediate MemoryStream and read the BitmapImage from there.

You should also write a view model class with property change notification:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private BitmapImage routeImage;

    public BitmapImage RouteImage
    {
        get { return routeImage; }
        set
        {
            routeImage = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(RouteImage)));
        }
    }

    public void LoadImage(string archiveName, string entryName)
    {
        using (var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(archiveName))
        {
            var entry = archive.GetEntry(entryName);
            if (entry != null)
            {
                using (var zipStream = entry.Open())
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    zipStream.CopyTo(memoryStream); // here
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;

                    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                    bitmap.BeginInit();
                    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                    bitmap.StreamSource = memoryStream;
                    bitmap.EndInit();

                    RouteImage = bitmap;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assign an instance of the view model to the DataContext of your Window:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = viewModel;

    viewModel.LoadImage(
        @"D:\Games\steamapps\common\RailWorks\Content\Routes\00000036-0000-0000-0000-000000002012\MainContent.ap",
        "RouteInformation/image.png");
}
```

and bind the `RouteImage` property like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding RouteImage}"/>
```

---

If you are intending to load large image file from the zip archive, I'd recommend to call the view model code in an async method:

```
public async Task LoadImageAsync(string archiveName, string entryName)
{
    RouteImage = await Task.Run(() => LoadImage(archiveName, entryName));
}

private BitmapImage LoadImage(string archiveName, string entryName)
{
    BitmapImage bitmap = null;

    using (var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(archiveName))
    {
        var entry = archive.GetEntry(entryName);
        if (entry != null)
        {
            using (var zipStream = entry.Open())
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                zipStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.Position = 0;

                bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                bitmap.BeginInit();
                bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmap.StreamSource = memoryStream;
                bitmap.EndInit();
                bitmap.Freeze(); // necessary when loaded in non-UI thread
            }
        }
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Call the method from an async Loaded event handler in your MainWindow:

```
Loaded += async (s, e) => await viewModel.LoadImageAsync
    @"D:\Games\steamapps\common\RailWorks\Content\Routes\00000036-0000-0000-0000-000000002012\MainContent.ap",
    "RouteInformation/image.png");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Clemens! The copy to the memorystream did the trick.  PropertyChanged is not needed, because I intend to load the image once in the class constructor. and the images are small. But you gave me a very useful example to work with. :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Sooner or later you'll certainly find the MVVM pattern *very* useful. I strongly recommend to always implement it, even in simple cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

In my work to remove an image from a zip container, that using a middle thread as per Clemens answer *only created an exception* and was not tenable.

Ultimately I was able to use this code to extract a `BitmapImage`:

```
public static class StreamExtensions
{
    public static BitmapImage ToImage(this Stream stream)
    {       
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.EndInit();

        return bitmap;
     }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var image = zipEntry.Open().ToImage();
```